# Is there a preferred, scholarly edition of the Gesta Danorum in English?

Tags: norse, source-request

Been meaning to read this for a while, but there are quite a few translations out there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The translation](https://www.amazon.ca/Saxo-Grammaticus-History-English-Commentary/dp/0859915026/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1479422420&sr=1-2) by Peter Fisher, with an introduction and commentary by Hilda Roderick Davidson, is easy to find, and reputable.